# Excel CountIfs with an or condition on Dates

Tags: excel, countif

Looking to try and find the following in Excel but am having issues getting this to work.

I have Dates in Column A which need to be checked against Dates in the Query Column to compare. I want to count all records where the comparison column is greater than the date in A5 or is an empty cell. There are other conditions that I will also want to check but cannot seem to get this to work.

=COUNTIFS(Query1[Purchased Date],OR(Query1[Purchased Date]="",Query1[Purchased Date]>A5))

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((Query1[Purchased Date]="")+(Query1[Purchased Date]>A5)>0))
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could add a condition that sits as a condition inside the sumproduct but outside of the condition that has --((Query1[Purchased Date]="")+(Query1[Purchased Date]>A5)>0)

Comment: not sure I understand.  You can add `AND` type by multiplying ie: `*(Query1[SomeOtherColumn] ="X"`) to the `((Query1[Purchased Date]="")+(Query1[Purchased Date]>A5)>0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array function instead of countif.
Suppose your dates are in the range A2:A25 and your reference date is in cell B2.

If you type in any other cell

```
=SUM((A2:A25>B2)+(A2:A25=""))
```

and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter it will give you the count you want.

This happens because Excel will resolve the first inner parentheses (A2:A25>B2) as an array of TRUE/FALSE, and does the same to the second (A2:A25=""). Next it will sum them, which is equivalent to the OR operation, and yields as a result an array of zeros (FALSE) and ones (TRUE). It wraps up by summing this array (with the function sum), all in one cell.

Comment: Remember to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter every time you finish editing your formula above.

Comment: This one did help however if I have more conditions that I needed to use against this condition to check in the array I believe I'll have to sum an array meeting the condition or use sumproduct against the arrays.

Comment: If you have more conditions, the only rule you have to follow is this: use + whenever it's an OR and * whenever it's an AND. And use parentheses as you would when writing with logical conditions.
I mean: 
`OR( A ; B)` becomes `(A + B) ` and 
`AND (A; B)` becomes  `(A * B)`.
Where A and B are your filter expressions, that resolve in TRUE or FALSE. You then can nest them as much as you want.
Example:
`OR(A ; AND (B ; C)) `
becomes
`(A + (B * C))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more of a comment than an answer, but in this particular case you can just add the two separate totals:

```
=COUNTIF(Query1[Purchased Date],"")+COUNTIF(Query1[Purchased Date],">"&A5)
```

because the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Whether this helps or not depends on what additional criteria you want to add.

BTW there are two issues with your original formula:

(1) If you are combining lists of values with OR logic, you have to use addition instead (as in the two answers which use Sum or Sumproduct).

(2) The syntax of a Countif or Countifs where the range has to be kept separate from the criteria won't let you do what you want to do, so this again leads you to Sum or Sumproduct.

Comment: Thanks Tom - unfortunately there are about 3-4 other combinations of if statements that I would need to include so the number of statements if to do each mutually exclusive becomes a bit messier to have to deal with.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Use countif(s) if you can, because it's more efficient, but if you can't, use sum(product).